# Missing data when recording model into JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginner and trying to save the model `todoModel` into `data.json`, but some elements `(title, description)` are not saved.

`app.js`

```
const http = require("http");
const todoRouter = require("./routes/todo.router");

const server = http.createServer(todoRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

`todo.router.js`

```
const url = require("url");
const todoController = require("../controllers/todo.controller");

const todoRouter = (req, res) => {
  const urlparse = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if (urlparse.pathname == "/todos" && req.method == "POST") {
    todoController.createTodo(req, res);
  }
};
module.exports = todoRouter;
```

`todo.controller.js`

```
const fs = require("fs");
class todoController {
 async createTodo(req, res) {
    req.on("data", (data) => {
      
      if (data) {
        todos.push(todoModel);

        fs.writeFile(
          "./data/data.json",
          JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2),
          (err) => {
            if (err) throw error;
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }}
```

`todo.model.js`

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const fs = require("fs");

const data = fs.readFileSync("./data/data.json");
const jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
const title = jsondata.title;
const description = jsondata.description;

const todoModel ={
  id: uuidv4(),
  title,
  description,
  dateOfCreate: new Date(),
  lastModified: new Date(),
  check: new Boolean(false),
};

module.exports = todoModel;
```

Saved model `todoModel` in `data.json` looks like that:

```
[
  {
    "id": "cb996b22-d9d8-49ee-8e35-6f8bfc005268",
    "dateOfCreate": "2021-11-06T14:53:28.608Z",
    "lastModified": "2021-11-06T14:53:28.608Z",
    "check": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Why have you screenshotted your JSON instead of including it here as text…? Please include all relevant code and other files in the body of your question as text, not as images. Potential answerers should not have to transcribe such data on their own. (It’s also arguably much easier to copy/paste than it is to screenshot, upload, then link.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i recommend to just export functions and constants and not variables or object witch can change. However i would rather use an function here

```
function getTodoModel() {
  const data = fs.readFileSync("./data/data.json");
  const jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
  const title = jsondata.title;
  const description = jsondata.description;

  return {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title,
    description,
    dateOfCreate: new Date(),
    lastModified: new Date(),
    check: new Boolean(false),
  }
}

module.exports = getTodoModel
```

Later you simply import your function and call it:

```
let todoModel = getTodoModel()
```

The variables will get evaluated

Comment: it doesn't work, the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Your values `title` and `description` don't have assigned a key in your `todoModel`. Just assign these values to proper keys in your object.

```js
const todoModel ={
  id: uuidv4(),
  title: title, // add key for title
  description: description, // and here add key for description
  dateOfCreate: new Date(),
  lastModified: new Date(),
  check: new Boolean(false),
};
```

But the problem doesn't stop just here. Your problem is that you read the JSON file, load its content and then write the content back without any modifications. In the file `todo.controller.js`, you load the `todoModel`, which loads the content of the file. Then you add this content to `todos` array and write it right back to the file. You don't do any modification to `todoModel`, so what it does is pretty much nothing.

Comment: the problem still exists.

Comment: @tan4ok I have added more info in the answer.

Comment: suggest, please, how to fix it

Comment: What your code suppose to do? @tan4ok

Comment: need, the data from the POST request to be written to data.json according to model todoModel в файле todo.model.js. Added a few more files with code.